# Amcharts Map: center description window in map area no matter the zoom level

Tags: amcharts

I want to show descriptions from map are no centered no matter the zoom level.

I can get the *stage coordinates* like:

```
amchart1.addListener("clickMapObject", function(event) {
    var stage = amchart1.coordinatesToStageXY(amchart1.getAreaCenterLatitude(event.mapObject), amchart1.getAreaCenterLongitude(event.mapObject));
    console.log(stage);
})
```

But how can I convert this result to screen coordinates. I'd like to center the description in the map area no matter what the zoom factor is.

Answer (score 0):

When I use `chart.openPopup` the modal is centered in the viewport no matter the zoom level. It does not appear that you have to use coordinates to achieve this.